# Ranking within Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ranking

I have an  array **$data** as below

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [user1] => Array
                (
                    [score] => 10
                )

            [user2] => Array
                (
                    [score] => 15
                )

            [user3] => Array
                (
                    [score] => 12
                )

            [user4] => Array
                (
                    [score] => 1
                )
)
```

I am looking for the Ranking of the array based on Score having maximum score as Rank 1

Output:

```
user2 -> 1
user3 -> 2
user1 -> 3
user4 -> 4
```

Any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php example3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function with descending option to achieve this

```
$array = array('data' => array('user1' => array('score' => 10 ),
                                'user2' => array('score' => 15),
                                'user3' => array('score' => 12),
                                'user4' => array('score' => 1),
                              )
                );

array_multisort($array['data'], SORT_DESC);
var_dump($array);
```

This will order your array to

```
array (size=1)
  'data' => 
    array (size=4)
      'user2' => 
        array (size=1)
          'score' => int 15
      'user3' => 
        array (size=1)
          'score' => int 12
      'user1' => 
        array (size=1)
          'score' => int 10
      'user4' => 
        array (size=1)
          'score' => int 1
```

Answer (score 1):

TO sort you array you have to use **asort($array)** function.